# Where can I know voltage between GND(ground) and each port of UNO R3?

Tags: arduino-uno, voltage

Currently I'm new to arduino uno r3.

Where can I find each voltage between each port and GND(ground)?

Or can the voltage be changed?

I don't want to break my led bulbs since large difference of 2 potentials

Comment: I don't really understand, what you mean. But the Uno runs on 5V, so the maximum voltage on its pins imposed by it is 5V.

Comment: I see. I'm too new to arduino.

Comment: https://majenko.co.uk/blog/what-exactly-gpio-pin

Comment: I'll read the article.

Comment: Maybe using a voltmeter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can measure each one at the output of the port (where you plug a connecting-wire to the port). Measure from that wire to ground with your DVM. It should be either 0v or 5v, depending on whether the port is set LOW or HIGH. (Or it could be pulsing from 0v - 5v - 0v - ... , if it is one of the PWM ports and the port has been set to provide a PWM output.) If the pin is in INPUT mode (and not INPUT_PULLUP), you're likely to read noise picked up by the connection between the pin and the meter, as an INPUT pin will be in high-impedance mode - no voltage will be asserted by the MCU, so the connection will behave almost like an un-connected wire, e.g., an antenna.

Answer (score 0):

5[V] is ideal EMF(electromotive force) of arduino UNO R3.

Since I stated "**ideal**" ,the actual EMF be slightly lower than 5[V].

In this instance , EMF can be assumed as voltage between GND and port of UNO R3 as ports are connected only by a wire.

Comment: EMF (Electromotive Force)? That’s a rather odd term to use in this instance. Just voltage will do.

Comment: 5V is not the EMF or Voltage of an Arduino Uno. It is the EMF or Voltage the microcontroller of the Arduino Uno (ATmega328) should be supplied with. If a digital pin is set to be high, it will have a voltage slightly under the supply voltage, depending of the amount of current that is drawn from that pin.

Comment: Oh,I see. I edited the answer.